# How to delete a forked repo on github?

Tags: github

I just deleted my forked repo on GitHub UI and after refreshing the page the repo is still there. From the command line I cannot pull or push to this repo any more (getting a message this repo does not exist). When I try to fork the repo again on the UI it I get a message that I already forked this repo. Is it normal behavior? How to reliably delete a forked repo?

Comment: How exactly did you "delete [your] forked repo on GitHub UI?

Comment: I think it's actually a current bug on Github: `October 21, 2018
20:00 Pacific Daylight TimeWe are continuing to repair a data storage system for GitHub.com. You may see inconsistent results during this process.` https://status.github.com/messages

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Settings page of your forked repo
2. Scroll down to the "Danger Zone" section at the bottom of the page
3. Click "Delete this repository"
4. At the prompt, enter the name of your forked repository
5. Click "I understand the consequences, delete this repository"
6. Delete the folder on your file system where you cloned the repository to

Having performed 1-6 you can, if you wish, refork the repository and reclone it to your machine.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to delete normal repo. you can follow this steps.

```
Go to forked repo - > Settings -> Delete this repository  (Under Danger Zone)
```